# Prepare number of sections and row before UITableViewController gets called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a subclass of `UITableViewController` where I have 2 properties that will defines the number of sections and number of rows in section

It seems the the delegate methods `numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int` get called before `viewDidLoad()` which is where I am initialising the 2 properties at currently. Therefore the 2 properties does not have any value when the delegate methods get called.

Where should I initialise these 2 value such that it will be ready for the delegate method.

Comment: How you initialize your UITableViewController? I've just tried with storyboard and viewDidLoad worked before those delegate methods.

Comment: Have you debug the code? simply add a breakpoint in viewDidLoad and another one in numberOfRowsInSection, which one will get reached first? :)

Comment: You should init those values in your `viewWillAppear` method. In the fact that `viewWillAppear` is called before `viewDidLoad` ...

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be calling that delegate func before `viewDidLoad`.

I just tested the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("whatt????")
}
```

When I run my app, this prints:

> viewDidLoad
>
> whatt???
>
> whatt???
>
> whatt???

I would test that your variables are properly initialized. If they are, you should have no problem using them to define how many rows/sections you have.